# Как сохранять пароль от ключа в FileZilla?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, filezilla

Для подключения по SFTP мы используем public key. Как мне в FileZilla сохранить пароль от этого ключа не на сессию, а навсегда?

FileZilla 3.15.0.2

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

«навсегда» — это значит «убрать пароль вообще».

как и в случае изменения/установки пароля, убрать его можно с помощью программы *ssh-keygen*, вызванной с опцией `-p`:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p
```

сначала будет запрошен путь к секретному ключу (с предложенным вариантом по умолчанию — `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, с которым можно согласиться, нажав <kbd>enter</kbd>, а можно ввести путь к другому файлу; можно вообще указать путь к файлу с помощью опции `-f /путь/к/секретному.ключу`).

затем будет запрошен существующий пароль (конечно, если установлен), и, если он введён правильно, дважды будет запрошен новый пароль. если оба раза ничего не вводить, а нажимать <kbd>enter</kbd>, пароль будет «пуст», т.е., секретный ключ **не будет** зашифрован, и ничего впоследствии не будет запрашиваться при использовании данного файла с секретным ключом.