# Деплой проекта с помощью git

Tags: git, ssh

Есть две машины - разработчика и сервер.
На сервере заведен пользователь git.
Под этим юзером установлен gitolite.
Заведен пользователь web, на этом же сервере.
Пользователь git входит в группу git и web.
Пользователь web состоит в группе web.
В папке /home/web/.ssh лежит файл config в котором прописаны настройки для ssh. У этого файла права - 600, иначе невозможно например сделать git clone git@project.git
Когда разработчик делает push в git@сервер, на сервере отрабатывает hook, hooks/post-receive, который должен протолкнуть изменения в /home/web/project:

> cd /home/web/project/
>
> git pull origin master

Но тут вылазит ошибка - bad permissins для файла config.
То что пользователи git и web входят в одну группу - без разницы, права 600 /home/.ssh/config позволяют читать этот файл только пользователю web. А если сменить их то перестает работать ssh:

> Because of the potential for abuse, this file must have strict
> permissions: read/write for the user, and not writable by others. It
> may be group-writable provided that the group in question contains
> only the user.

Я не совсем понимаю в линуксе. Подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: 'cd /home/web/project/ git pull origin master' - что это, две команды или одна?

Comment: две команды, не перенес

Comment: Поробуйте - `ssh -T git@<gitserver>` - сервер задайте как в git clone.

Comment: **права 600 /home/.ssh/config** - а это что за папочка?

Comment: Это не папка а файл с настройками для ssh: Host gitbox 
    User git
    Hostname example.com
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key

Comment: Тогда -  /home/git/.ssh/config

Answer (score 3):

У вас повидимому не сконфигурирован доступ по `ssh` для git пользователя. Посмотрите - `ls -la /home/git/.ssh`. Как `git` пользователь поставьте там необходимые права:

```
cd; chmod 700 .ssh/; chmod 600 .ssh/config .ssh/id_rsa 

ssh -T git@<gitserver>
```

Если всё хорошо, то - `git pull` - тоже должен работать.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078005/git-post-receive-hook-which-connects-to-remote-via-ssh-and-git-pulls) я нашёл небольшую дискуссию по вашей тематике.

Comment: возможно вы правы, я только сейчас задумался что нужно положить ключ в папку /home/git/.ssh для доступа по ssh к web, я раньше думал что связь односторонняя ведь web делает clone,pull,push а git только отдает и принимает, хотя скорее всего чтоб отработал хук с git на web тоже нужен ключ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все так сделал, работает

Answer (score 0):

фактически вам надо выполнить набор команд от имени другого пользователя. в *unix*-подобных операционных системах общепринятой практикой в таких случаях является использование программы [`sudo`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

1. поместите необходимые команды в файл, расположив его в наиболее подходящем для подобных скриптов месте — каталоге `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   $ echo 'cd /home/web/project/ && git pull origin master' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/произвольное.имя
   ```
2. добавьте ему биты исполнимости:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod +x /urs/local/bin/произвольное.имя
   ```
3. разрешите пользователю *git* исполнять этот файл от имени пользователя *web* без подтверждения паролем. для этого запустите редактирование файла в каталоге `/etc/sudoers.d` (имя файла произвольное, но не должно содержать точки):

   ```
   $ sudo visudo /etc/sudoers.d/allow-git-run-command-as-web
   ```

   вставьте в него строку:

   ```
   git ALL=(web) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/произвольное.имя
   ```

   сохраните и закройте редактор. благодаря тому, что редактор был запущен через «обёртку» *visudo*, после этого будет произведён синтаксический анализ ваших изменений и, если есть ошибки, будет предложено внести изменения или отказаться от редактирования вообще. это полезно, т.к. в случае ошибок в конфигурации программа *sudo* вообще откажется работать и вы даже не сможете эти ошибки исправить.

теперь в `hooks/post-receive` вы можете поместить вызов скрипта:

```
sudo -u web /usr/local/bin/произвольное.имя
```

Comment: Не проще ли просто ssh web@server 'набор команд'?

Comment: @0xdb, 1. если и проще, то ненамного. 2. менее безопасно — даёт пользователю *git* возможность выполнения **любой** команды от имени пользователя *web*.

Comment: это конечно правильно, но п.2 с помощью  `command="gitpull.sh"` в ключах web тоже поправимо.

Comment: @0xdb, т.е., получаем явно более сложное решение. вот и ответ на ваш вопрос из первого комментария.

Comment: @0xdb, стоит также отметить, что вариант с *ssh* будет и менее универсален. например, он не подойдёт в случае, если полноценная оболочка пользователю *web* не предоставляется.

Comment: Все сделал. Теперь при команде git push с любой машины на git@server, то как и раньше изменения уходят, а при отработке хука remote: Permission denied (publickey).
remote: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote: Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: Но если зайти на сервер под пользователем git и выполнить руками .post-receive, то спрашивает пароль, и все отрабатывает на ура

Comment: @egorrrr, какой ещё пароль??? пароль к секретному ключу пользователя *web*? так [уберите его](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583082/178576).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все так сделал, работает