# VBoxManage создание общих виртуальных машин из php shell_exec

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, virtualbox, exec

При попытки использования VBoxManage из php shell_exec (Apache под Ububntu 14.04) все созданные виртуальные машины не видны в VirtualBox, они живут своей жизнью(вероятно принадлежат другому пользователя или группе).

Как мне правильно создавать виртуальные машины из php при помощи VBoxManage что бы они были видны в VirtualBox и наооборот: создавать виртуальные машины в virtualbox, которые будут видны при вызове VBoxManage list vms из php?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587377/178576

Comment: Решил проблему созданием общей группы и пользователя для виртуальных машин. В настройках apache выставил нужную группу и пользователя.