# Автоматическая авторизация через SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

**1.** Генерирую RSA-ключ:

```
ssh-keygen
```

При генерации оставляю имя файла по умолчанию, ввожу только кодовую фразу (`passphrase`).

---

**2.** Копирую его на удалённый сервер:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa host.example.com
```

---

**3.** Авторизируюсь:

```
ssh host.example.com
```

---

**4.** Идёт запрос кодовой фразы; ввожу её и происходит авторизация. Следующий раз в течении сессии (пока я не выйду (Logout)) при повторной авторизации на удалённом сервере уже не запрашивается кодовая фраза, а сразу происходит авторизация.

---

#### Вопросы

1. Так и должно быть? То есть мне казалось, что если я уже один раз авторизировался (ввёл кодовую фразу), то дальше это не требуется вне зависимости от сессии.
2. Как сделать полностью автоматическую авторизацию? То есть, например, чтобы после перезагрузки компьютера, я просто набрал `ssh host.example.com` и очутился на удалённом хосте, без ввода кодовой фразы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так и должно быть? То есть мне казалось, что если я уже один раз авторизировался (ввёл кодовую фразу), то дальше это не требуется вне зависимости от сессии.

Так и должно быть. Кодовая фраза - есть дополнительный этап обеспечения безопасности. Однако, если вы не планируете терять носитель с приватным ключем - смело делайте новый ключ с пустой кодовой фразой. Авторизация будет полностью автоматом.

В противном случае - нужно будет вводить один раз на сессию, иными словами - вводить при логине. Тогда в чем смысл ключа, если ваша секретная фраза - и так секретная? ))

Comment: Да, я так и сделал ... Только не совсем понял ваш вопрос ... Можете переформулировать его?

Comment: У меня скоре не вопрос, а утверждение: если "приватный"(читаем, секретный) ключ вы не сможете сохранить в секрете - высокая вероятность, что и пасс-фразу вы "передадите" шпийонам вместе с ключем) Шютка. Маленькая, грюзинская. Просто берегите приватный ключ - и этого будет достаточно для обеспечения приемлемого уровня приватной секретности.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, шифрация секретного ключа («кодовой фразой») для того и была реализована, чтобы даже если файл с секретным ключом попал в руки злоумышленника, то он не смог бы этим воспользоваться. даже ношение этого файла с собой (например, на съёмном носителе), не страхует от потери/кражи (уже самого носителя). а вот факт шифрования гарантирует, что пока вы сами не сообщите никому «кодовую фразу», никто не сможет воспользоваться вашим секретным ключом, даже обладая файлом, в котором он хранится.

Answer (score 2):

> Следующий раз в течении сессии (пока я не выйду (Logout)) при повторной авторизации на удалённом сервере уже не запрашивается кодовая фраза, а сразу происходит авторизация.
>   Так и должно быть? То есть мне казалось, что если я уже один раз авторизировался (ввёл кодовую фразу), то дальше это не требуется вне зависимости от сессии.

вы не упоминаете о явном использовании программы `ssh-add`, поэтому уже сам факт того, что при выполнении `$ ssh машина` **хоть иногда не запрашивается** пароль (*passphrase*, «кодовая фраза»), которым зашифрован ключ, выглядит странным.

возможно, у вас в системе установлена версия *openssh* >= 7.2. уточнить версию можно, например, так:

```
$ ssh -V
```

в этой версии появилась возможность с помощью опции `addkeystoagent` автоматически передавать расшифрованный ключ программе `ssh-agent`. вот что об этом написано в логе изменений (см. также описание в `$ man ssh_config` и `$ man ssh`, если у вас версия *openssh* 7.2 или выше):

> [ssh(1): Add an AddKeysToAgent client option which can be set to
>      'yes', 'no', 'ask', or 'confirm', and defaults to 'no'.  When
>      enabled, a private key that is used during authentication will be
>      added to ssh-agent if it is running (with confirmation enabled if
>      set to 'confirm').](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2)

но по умолчанию эта опция имеет значение `no` (не передавать). возможно, она переопределена в глобальном и/или пользовательском конфигурационном файле. см. вывод:

```
$ grep -i addkeystoagent /etc/ssh/ssh_config ~/.ssh/config
```

что это за «звери» — `ssh-add` и `ssh-agent` — кратко я описывал в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576). после его прочтения вам, надеюсь, станет понятнее, почему сохранённый в памяти программы `ssh-agent` расшифрованнный ключ может быть использован неоднократно в течение *x-сессии* без необходимости ввода «кодовой фразы» каждый раз при запуске команды `$ ssh машина`, **но** будет «утрачен» при перезапусе *x-сессии* (т.е., после logout-а). ведь процесс `ssh-agent`-а будет перезапущен, и «забудет» обо всех расшифрованных ключах.

> Как сделать полностью автоматическую авторизацию? То есть, например, чтобы после перезагрузки компьютера, я просто набрал ssh host.example.com и очутился на удалённом хосте, без ввода кодовой фразы.

вот [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583082/178576) на абсолютно идентичный вопрос.