# Azure DevOps, config file, SSH error: shell request failed on channel 0

Tags: git, ssh, azure

Возникла проблема при подключении к репозиторию Azure DevOps с помощью ssh ключа.

Вот так выглядит мой `config` файл:

```
Host azure
    HostName ssh.dev.azure.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/AzureKey
```

`AzureKey` сгенерированный мною ключ. Он подключен к аккаунту.

Ключ проверял с помощью `ssh-agent` и `ssh-add` - никаких проблем не возникает (могу и пушить и пулить), но когда использую `ssh azure` вылетает ошибка:
`shell request failed on channel 0` и соответственно, во время пуша в репозиторий я получаю ошибку аунтификации.

Также с помощью `config` файла подключался к github и bitbucket - никаких проблем не возникало: в результате мог спокойно пушить и пулить без повторного ввода кодовой фразы.

Вот полный вывод при использовании `ssh azure`:

```
$ ssh azure
debug2: resolving "ssh.dev.azure.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ssh.dev.azure.com [40.68.34.220] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/AzureKey type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/AzureKey-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHBlackbox.10
debug1: no match: SSHBlackbox.10
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ssh.dev.azure.com:22 as 'mikle'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ssh.dev.azure.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 1028/2048
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:ohD8VZEXGWo6Ez8GSEJQ9WpafgLFsOfLOtGGQCQo6Og
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ssh.dev.azure.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 40.68.34.220
debug1: Host 'ssh.dev.azure.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug2: bits set: 1048/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/AzureKey (0x600061370), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:t42carn2fmAHtiMGjG/E7QOG10jlvL89OpUmIQIj+kw /c/Users/mikle/.ssh/AzureKey
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:t42carn2fmAHtiMGjG/E7QOG10jlvL89OpUmIQIj+kw
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:t42carn2fmAHtiMGjG/E7QOG10jlvL89OpUmIQIj+kw
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mikle/.ssh/AzureKey':
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ssh.dev.azure.com ([40.68.34.220]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 1048576 rmax 16384
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 75
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить возникшую проблему?

Comment: а почему вы решили, что отказ предоставить вам сеанс оболочки на этом сервере является «проблемой»? скорее «проблемой» (точнее, дикой дырой в безопасности данного сервера) было бы удачное получение такого сеанса. вы, вероятно, пытаетесь **чего-то** добиться, но делаете для этого не совсем то, что следовало бы. а нам не рассказываете, чего же именно вы добиваетесь.

Comment: Я хочу использовать ssh azure для того, чтоб не вводить постоянно passphrase для ключа, когда я делаю push/pull. В случае с github или bitbucket все срабатывает отлично, то есть после использования ssh myHost, я ввожу passphrase и могу спокойно пушить в свой репозиторий сколько угодно раз до закрытия консоли без повторного ввода кодовой фразы, как при использовании `ssh-agent`  и `ssh add` Но с DevOps возникает, описанная в вопросе, проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### новый вариант ответа:

как оказалось, вы пытаетесь оптимизировать добавление секретной части ключа *ssh-agent-у* — чтобы не писать каждый раз после начала x-сессии явную команду:

```
$ ssh-add /путь/к/секретной/части/ключа
```

а требовалось вам вводить эту команду потому, что *ssh-agent* **не** запоминал уже расшифрованный ключ, и его надо было расшифровывать при каждой команде программы *git*, осуществляющей связь с удалённым хранилищем: *clone*, *pull*, *push*, *fetch* (и некоторыми другими).

так вот чтобы программа *ssh* «передавала» ключ *ssh-agent-у* после первой же его расшифровки, надо добавить в начало файла `~/.ssh/config` строку:

```
addkeystoagent yes
```

теперь *ssh-agent* получит расшифрованный ключ и последующие (в течение x-сессии) вызовы программы *ssh*, которым будет нужен этот ключ, не будут требовать от вас ввода «кодовой фразы» («passphrase») для расшифровки ключа.

про эту опцию упоминалось уже, например, здесь: [Автоматическая авторизация через SSH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604684/178576) и здесь: [Где хранится ключ SSH в OS X после удаления самого файла ключа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/815820/178576)

#### первый вариант ответа:

> Вот полный вывод при использовании `ssh azure`:

вы не изложили цель, с которой подключаетесь. но можно предположить, что «просто для проверки, что ключ подходит».

поздравляю! ваш ключ опознан как известный:

> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)

вот только интерактивный сеанс оболочки на данном сервере для пользователей, понятно, недоступен. о чём вас и извещают:

> shell request failed

---

судя по изложенному в [этом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate), к примеру, документе, данное доменное имя (`ssh.dev.azure.com`) используется для доступа к git-хранилищам. например, можно клонировать уже существующее:

```
$ git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:путь/к/хранилищу
```

так как псевдоним (`azure`) для данного доменного имени вы уже завели в `~/.ssh/config`, можете его использовать вместо доменного имени:

```
$ git clone git@azure:путь/к/хранилищу
```

а чтобы ещё пользователя (`git`) не указывать, можно к той же секции, что вы записали в `~/.ssh/config`, добавить строку:

```
user git
```

и тогда можно писать совсем коротко:

```
$ git clone azure:путь/к/хранилищу
```

Comment: Я хочу использовать `ssh azure` для того, чтоб не вводить постоянно passphrase для ключа, когда я делаю push/pull.

Comment: В случае с github или bitbucket все срабатывает отлично, то есть после использования `ssh myHost`, я ввожу passphrase и могу спокойно пушить в свой репозиторий сколько угодно раз до закрытия консоли без повторного ввода кодовой фразы.

Но с DevOps возникает, описанная в вопросе, проблема.

Comment: в комментарии вы изложили [совершенно другой вопрос](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts#rememberpassphrase). его стоит задать отдельно.

Comment: Я знаю про возможность использования ssh-agent, но таким образом мне каждый раз при запуске консоли приходится писать путь к моему ключу. config файл позволяет сделать тоже самое, что и `ssh-agent`,  но без указания пути к ключу.

Comment: смысл вашего последнего комментария от меня ускользает. есть подозрение, что вы не верно представляете себе, [что такое ssh-agent, для чего он нужен и как он работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576).

Comment: давайте начнём с самого начала. вот вы включили компьютер и вводите команду `$ git clone azure:путь/к/хранилищу`. и что, программа *ssh*, запускаемая «под капотом», на спрашивает у вас «passphrase» для ключа `~/.ssh/AzureKey`?

Comment: если таки спрашивает, но ssh-agent не запоминает расшифрованный ключ (и. например, `$ git pull`, вновь запрашивает «passphrase»), то вам надо включить авто-добавление ключей ssh-agent-у. см. про [addkeystoagent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815853/178576)

Comment: При клонировании запросило passphrase, затем запустил git pull - опять запросило passphrase, добавил addkeystoagent в конфигурационный файл, опять склонировал репозиторий и git pull сработал без passphrase, как вы и написали. Это более чем приемлемый способ авторизации, за это вам большое спасибо.

Comment: «каждый раз опять клонировать» не надо. ключ добавляется агенту при первом (за время x-сессии) ssh-обращении к хосту. которое может быть инициировано любой из команд программы git, взаимодействующей с удалённым хранилищем: clone, pull, push, fetch (и некоторыми другими).

Comment: ну и в конце концов можно просто оставить ключ расшифрованным. `$ ssh-keygen -p -f /путь/к/файлу/с/секретной/частью/ключа` и ввести пустую строку вместо passphrase.