# Как в скрипте автоматически добавить passphrase для ssh-add

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Пытаюсь настроить деплой в travis CI, т.е есть скрип который автоматом должен на удаленной машине добавить приватный ключ, настроить ssh, подключится к другому серверу по ssh и залить туда файл. Вот часть кода:

- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

Дальше нужно выполнять команду:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Но ssh-add запрашивает passphrase

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/travis/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Находил несколько вариантов решения, например:

```
echo -e "\n" | ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Или:

- echo 'echo SSH_PASSPHRASE' > ~/.echo_ps && chmod 700 ~/.echo_ps
- cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | SSH_ASKPASS=~/.echo_ps ssh-add -

Варианты выше почемуто не сработали.

Подскажите как можно автоматизировать ввод passphrase в скрипте?

Comment: если нужно полностью исключить взаимодействие человека со скриптом, то используй не шифрованный ключ, а ради безопасности максимально ограничь, что с его помощью можно сделать на удалённой машине... хранить пароль в скрипте в открытом виде — всё равно, что хранить ключ на цепочке рядом с дверью.

Comment: наличие passphrase в файле, а не в голове, полностью лишает её использование какого-либо смысла. [уберите её](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583082/178576) и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте expect

Установка: `sudo apt install expect` на Debian.

Будем считать, что `id_rsa` лежит в текущем каталоге, и на нем уже права 700 (иначе скрипт не сработает).

Файл `expect.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#
# Интерактивный режим для любых программ
#

# лимит времени выполнения
set timeout 3

# объявляем переменные
set password [lindex $argv 0]

# запускаем программу
spawn ssh-add id_rsa

# ждем этого приглашения, на что отвечаем паролем
expect "Enter passphrase for id_rsa:" { send "$password\r" }

expect {
  # если выскочило это, то пароль не верен, выходим с ошибкой
  "Bad passphrase, try again for id_rsa:" { exit 1 }
  # выходим без ошибки
  eof { exit 0 }
}
```

Затем `chmod +x ./expect.sh`, `./expect.sh пароль-для-id_rsa`.

Также посмотрите как работает `autoexpect ssh-add id_rsa`

Ссылки:

- [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)
- [статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/328436/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, ответ помог решить проблему

Comment: @Къяр, пожалуйста, можете отметить его как решение?

Comment: Отметил, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант, но нужно создавать дополнительный скрипт:

**ap_helper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
exec cat
```

**my_ssh.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -sp "Enter passphrase: " PASS

echo
sleep 0.5s
DIR=~/.ssh
SSH_HLP=$(dirname "$0")/ap_helper.sh

echo "$PASS"| SSH_ASKPASS=$SSH_HLP ssh-add "$DIR/bitbucket.org" 2> /dev/null
echo "$PASS"| SSH_ASKPASS=$SSH_HLP ssh-add "$DIR/github.com" 2> /dev/null
echo "$PASS"| SSH_ASKPASS=$SSH_HLP ssh-add "$DIR/gitlab.com" 2> /dev/null

ssh-add -l
```

Взято [отсюда](https://ifireball.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/automatic-loading-of-ssh-keys-from-scripts/).