# Заполнение read полей в консоли linux с помощью python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, автоматизация

Хотел написать программу для автоматизации создания профилей через .sh скрипт. Хотелось бы чтоб python скрипт сам вводил данные просто взяв их из списка.
Конечно было бы проще вшить это в сам .sh скрипт, но уж слишком плохо знаю bash.
Сейчас делаю что-то вроде

```
os.system('./script_name.sh first_arg second_arg')
```

Но вот эти аргументы не были предусмотрены скриптом изначально, немного подкорректировал, но видимо неправильно. В общем не работает.

Вся проблема в том, что я не могу вводить данные в поля `read` в этом скрипте. Это и есть вопрос, как вводить данные в поля `read` bash скрипта через Python в консоли linux. (может библиотека какая есть, может трюк какой)

Comment: посмотретие название переменных после `read`, к примеру `read -p "введите first_arg" first_arg`, закоментируйте эту строку `#` и укажите что эта переменная из входящего параметра `first_arg="${1}"`

Comment: Чуть выше написали как поправить sh-скрипт, чтобы переместить интерактивные вопросы в аргументы вызова команды. Другой способ - использовать [expect](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), вот [мой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940446/287469) для ssh-add, в вашем случае можно сделать аналогично.